# Writing to an excel sheet in a JAR file

Tags: java, apache-poi, executable-jar

I made a Java project in netbeans that uses data from an excel sheet. There is functionality in my project that allows the user to read and write to the excel sheet. I have used the Apache POI library to do this. The program works well in Netbeans IDE 17 but when I try to do the same in a JAR file, I cannot write to the excel sheet.

this is what my code initially looked like:

```
if(addordel.equals("add")){
            File file = new File("./src/Pick4list.xlsx");
            Workbook workbook;
            try {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                int rowNum = -1;
                for (Row row : sheet) {
                    if (row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().equals(datenum)) {
                        rowNum = row.getRowNum();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (rowNum >= 0) {
                    for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
                        Cell cell = sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(i);
                        if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK) {
                            if (i - 1 < dateslist.size()) {
                                String dateStr = dateslist.get(i - 1);
                                cell = sheet.getRow(rowNum).createCell(i);
                                cell.setCellValue(dateStr);
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                workbook.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Pick4gen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Pick4gen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

I've read answers from stackoverflow and changed my code to the following:

```
if(addordel.equals("add")){
            InputStream file = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/Pick4list.xlsx");
            Workbook workbook;
            try {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                int rowNum = -1;
                for (Row row : sheet) {
                    if (row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().equals(datenum)) {
                        rowNum = row.getRowNum();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (rowNum >= 0) {
                    for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
                        Cell cell = sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(i);
                        if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK) {
                            if (i - 1 < dateslist.size()) {
                                String dateStr = dateslist.get(i - 1);
                                cell = sheet.getRow(rowNum).createCell(i);
                                cell.setCellValue(dateStr);
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                workbook.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Pick4gen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Pick4gen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

I've build the project after this. Opened the jar file using WinRAR, created a folder called "data" and placed my Excel sheet there. This seems to be working since I have another snippet of code that simply reads data from the excel and stores the data in a HashMap (I could print the data from the HashMap so I understood that the program could read the excel sheet). I need help as to how I can change the code so that I can write to the excel sheet in the JAR.

I want to create this program in such a way that no matter on which computer I run the JAR file, I want to be able to read from the excel sheet and also be able to make changes to it (the changes must be saved). Please guide me.

Comment: You can’t reference ‘src’ in your code, it won’t exist once the project is compiled and packaged. You also can’t write to the jar file - or at least not as you’re expecting it to work. The file should be externalised

Comment: oh ok, thanks for pointing that out. How can I externalise the file? Let's assume I send this jar to someone, would I also need to send the excel sheet along with it?

Comment: Well, it would depend, but you can read the file from the Jar, maybe save it to a temp file, and the allow the user to save the final file to a chosen location. Alternatively, you could use a installer and save these kind of files to a “commonly known location”

Answer (score 1):

Whilst some OSes (*cough* windows *cough*) are, or at least used to be, fundamentally unsafely designed, **in general** the notion that an app can write to its own data files is a very bad idea, and thus non-broken OSes don't let you. Even windows which tended to go with the deployment model of 'you have e.g. `C:\Program Files\MyApp` and myapp stores user data and its config file (that is editable in the app itself) in there', is now moving away from this, with a 'My Documents' folder where docs and settings go instead of the app's own 'program files' folder.

The conclusion is that 'can I write to my own jar' is a definitely NO. On some OSes you might be able to, but writing your app such that 'I need to modify my own jar or I do not work' means your app only works on unsafe OSes / now-safe OSes but only if you use the unsafe legacy deployment model.

So what's the real solution?

**Templating**.

When the user wants an excel sheet and edit it in place, the flow goes like this:

- User indicates they want to do this. Possibly, 'start your app for the first time' is enough of an indication. Possibly they click some button someplace.
- You read in an excel sheet as you do now - using `.getResource`. Which you didn't quite use correctly, it's `MyClass.class.getResource`, not `getClass().getResource` (the latter breaks if you ever subclass, the former wouldn't).
- You then save it **not to your jar file but to the documents folder**. Unfortunately finding the right place is somewhat tricky, in that you'll end up having to write some platform-dependent code (if user is on windows, save here. If on mac, save there, and so on). But the basic gist is:
- Use `System.getProperty("user.home")` to find the user's home dir. Save there, or possibly be 'nice' and save in a subdir. For example on mac you optimally would do:

```
Path p = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents");
```

and save there. That "Documents" thing is more specific.

- Alternatively, pop open a save dialog and let the user choose where to save it.

The 'template' XLS in your jar file *never changes*. (It can't; its in a file your process cannot write to, or at least should not write to).
Hence the name 'template'.